# "Sending" mishloach manot by serving them

Tags: halacha, purim, meal-seudah, hachnasat-orchim-guests, mishloach-manot

The obligation on Purim is to "send" 2 foods to another person. The *Mishna Brurah* (*Hilchot Megillah* 695:4) says that one may exchange *se'udah* food with a neighbor and is *yotzei* (21) even if (and I admit, my understanding may be wrong) that sender is going over to that neighbor to share in the *se'udah* later and will end up eating his own food.

What if my neighbor comes over after *megillah* reading? Can I given him his *mishloach* *manot* while he is in my house and eat it with him in my living room?

Can this be taken a step further? If I am hosting my neighbor in my house for *se'udah*, does my serving him a meal count as both the *se'udah* for him and my "sending" of ready made food? Can I be *mekayem* my *chiyuv* simply by hosting friends at the *se'udah* in my house and serving them (since then I won't be using a *shaliach*).

Is there some essence to the *mitzvah* that requires taking it out of my house, or "sending" it away, or is the change in who eats it, regardless of location what is important?

Comment: I don't see why you would not be Yotzei. People should be spending more time and money on Matanos LeEvyonim anyway instead of all these candy bars and hamentashen.

Comment: IIRC Rambam (based on Megillah 7b) says that you are yotzei mishloach manos by having a guy over for the seudah. (*some take this as proof of the Trumas HaDeshen over the Manos Halevi...whether or not they actually argue is a matter for another time*)

Answer (score 4):

It's a safek if one is *yotzei* like this or not. It's best to be machmir and send more to a different person. *Mikra'ei Kodesh - Hilchot Purim* by Rabbi [Moshe Harari](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A8%D7%99), 12:24.

> המזמין את חברו לסעוד אצלו ביום פורים, ספק אם יצא בכך ידי חובת משלוח מנות. וטוב להחמיר ולשלוח מנה נוספת במקום מנה זו.

He cites the Kaf Hachayim ([OC 695:42](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14425&st=&pgnum=348)) for this.

The Kaf Hachayim also writes that if you explicitly hand your guest two foods with the statement that these are your mishloach manot, it counts.

Comment: Seemingly the eitzah of giving the food to him and saying "this is shaloch manos" takes away any doubt?

Comment: @Yehoshua Apparently.

Comment: I imagine the custom of "eating out" wasn't always so prevelant and that's why we'd need to send to people. Now a days it's not like that, so...I was by a seudah one year where the bal habayis brought out plates of chicken, kugel, etc and said to each person "here is your shelach manos! Here is your shelach manos!"

Comment: I received some halachot from my Rav and he included this "Inviting another person, or family to Purim Se’udah does not satisfy the Mitzvah of MM. Rivevot Ephrayim (RE) 8:388:2)" though I have not checked the source.