# Do relatives count as Rey'eyhu?

Tags: halacha, mishloach-manot, kerovim-close-relatives

Follow up to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56105/sending-mishloach-manot-by-serving-them).

The obligation on Purim is "mishlo'ach manot, ish l'rey'eyhu", the sending of food, a man to his neighbor. Do relatives counts towards the concept of "neighbor"?

Can a man hand his wife lunch from the fridge before she goes to work and say, "Here, honey" and have it count? Can food that they both own count, or what if he stops by the store on the way home and buys some extra food? What about a father making breakfast or lunch for his child -- does that qualify for giving food to a neighbor?

Comment: FWIW MB 695:25 quotes an opinion that a married woman doesn’t send Mishloach Manos, as her husband does it for her. He writes that one should be stringent, but it’s noteworthy that there’s an opinion according to which your question doesn’t even start.

Comment: SA OC 695:4 rules that a man should not send Mishloach Manos to a woman. However, since the reason is that it may be doubtful Kiddushin, seemingly this would not be a problem in the case you discuss, so that doesn’t settle the issue either.

Comment: @DonielF even under 695:25 what about a man handing food to a 13 year old son who lives in the house? (or, because, as you say, 695:4 doesn't apply) to his wife?

Comment: 1. אשתו כגופו - does not count 2. Kids that are סמוכים על שלחנו dont count as he's obligated to support them 3. Grown up kids who live separately do count as  there's no Halachic obligation of supporting or providing food.

Answer (score 1):

The Shu"t Levushei Mordechai OC Tinyana siman 9 beings a proof from a Rebbi to talmid relationship that it would be mutar ,so certainly a son to a father would also count.He also brings a proof from Mishlei 27:10 which uses the term reiah (like reihu) .

(Regarding a husband giving to a wife I can see an issue with that because we usually employ the dictum" ishto kgifo" . So giving MM to yourself does not count)

Text:

[image]

Comment: Maybe https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/שולחן_ערוך_אורח_חיים_שסו_י implies the opposite

Comment: That's a totally diff halacha,MM is to spread kirva and achdus,whats the issue in doing that with family,kal vchomer its sometimes needed more in family

Comment: You may need technically to make a notable Kinyan. Giving food to a Samukh on Shulchano may not count technically.

Comment: For halacha l'maaseh,one should be machmir and just send to a non relative,and send with shaliach,and send in two separate containers, and send 3 eggs worth for each manna,and have two separate minim,and should be chashuv and for the meal,so on and so forth,but bshas hadchak I think this Shu"t is satisfactory